# How to enter Japanese-encoded password when extracting from zip file?

Tags: linux, command-line, passwords, zip, japanese

Zip file here: https://sp.seiga.nicovideo.jp/seiga/im4274119
https://bowlroll.net/file/50417

It contains another zip file, Taboo.zip. The password is "ジークハイル", but with Japanese encoding.

```
$ unzip -P "$(echo ジークハイル|iconv -f utf8 -t cp932)" 'Taboo.zip'
Archive:  Taboo.zip
  inflating: Taboo/gz1x.bmp          
  error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
$ unzip -P wrong-password 'Taboo.zip'
Archive:  Taboo.zip
   skipping: Taboo/gz1x.bmp          incorrect password
```

The password is correct, but there is another error, likely this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50129033

In other cases with this error, I've found that either file-roller or the right-click Extract option from Nautilus or Nemo was able to extract these files; I think in those cases the error came from having a file with 0 size in the zip file, with unzip handling everything up to that point.

I just don't see a way to use a non-Unicode password with these other programs. This puts the bit sequence into clipboard:

```
 echo ジークハイル|iconv -f utf8 -t cp932|xclip -i -selection clipboard
```

But can't paste this into GUI password prompt (also can't paste it into unzip's command-line prompt using gnome-terminal and bash). Can verify that it was correctly stored:

```
$ xclip -o -selection clipboard
�W�[�N�n�C��
```

It's just that ctrl-V (or shift-ctrl-V, with terminal) to paste doesn't work.

I also tried setting environment variable, 'LANG=ja_JP.UTF8 file-roller Taboo.zip', but I think it still uses some type of Unicode internally including for the password prompt, because entering 'ジークハイル' at the prompt still doesn't work.

So, is there a program that lets you enter the password as a command-line option and, unlike unzip, lets you ignore errors in the zip file?

Comment: Have you tried 7zip CLI `7z`? https://linux.die.net/man/1/7z

Comment: I verified that it works with proper zip files, but it reports a data error for this one. ' echo hi > test;  zip -P "$(echo イ|iconv -f utf8 -t cp932)" ar.zip test; unzip -P "$(echo イ|iconv -f utf8 -t cp932)" ar.zip;  7z x -P"$(echo イ|iconv -f utf8 -t cp932)" ar.zip;   7z x -P"$(echo ジークハイル|iconv -f utf8 -t cp932)" Taboo.zip' ERROR: Data Error in encrypted file. Wrong password? : Taboo/gz1x.bmp

Answer (score 0):

Dealing just with the `invalid compressed data to inflate` error, I don't think the issue you linked (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50129033) is relevant here. The internal structure of `Taboo.zip`, shown below, looks ok. There are no unexpected data descriptors present. That suggests the zip file is corrupt.

```
$ zipdetails Taboo.zip 

0000 LOCAL HEADER #1       04034B50
0004 Extract Zip Spec      14 '2.0'
0005 Extract OS            00 'MS-DOS'
0006 General Purpose Flag  0000
0008 Compression Method    0000 'Stored'
000A Last Mod Time         451FACBD 'Sun Aug 31 22:37:58 2014'
000E CRC                   00000000
0012 Compressed Length     00000000
0016 Uncompressed Length   00000000
001A Filename Length       0006
001C Extra Length          0000
001E Filename              'Taboo/'

0024 LOCAL HEADER #2       04034B50
0028 Extract Zip Spec      14 '2.0'
0029 Extract OS            00 'MS-DOS'
002A General Purpose Flag  0001
     [Bit  0]              1 'Encryption'
     [Bits 1-2]            0 'Normal Compression'
002C Compression Method    0008 'Deflated'
002E Last Mod Time         451FABEC 'Sun Aug 31 22:31:24 2014'
0032 CRC                   E90636CA
0036 Compressed Length     00005358
003A Uncompressed Length   00C00036
003E Filename Length       000E
0040 Extra Length          0000
0042 Filename              'Taboo/gz1x.bmp'
0050 PAYLOAD

53A8 CENTRAL HEADER #1     02014B50
53AC Created Zip Spec      3F '6.3'
53AD Created OS            00 'MS-DOS'
53AE Extract Zip Spec      14 '2.0'
53AF Extract OS            00 'MS-DOS'
53B0 General Purpose Flag  0000
53B2 Compression Method    0000 'Stored'
53B4 Last Mod Time         451FACBD 'Sun Aug 31 22:37:58 2014'
53B8 CRC                   00000000
53BC Compressed Length     00000000
53C0 Uncompressed Length   00000000
53C4 Filename Length       0006
53C6 Extra Length          0024
53C8 Comment Length        0000
53CA Disk Start            0000
53CC Int File Attributes   0000
     [Bit 0]               0 'Binary Data'
53CE Ext File Attributes   00000010
     [Bit 4]               Directory
53D2 Local Header Offset   00000000
53D6 Filename              'Taboo/'
53DC Extra ID #0001        000A 'NTFS FileTimes'
53DE   Length              0020
53E0   Reserved            00000000
53E4   Tag1                0001
53E6   Size1               0018
53E8   Mtime               01CFC51864BBECD5 'Sun Aug 31 13:37:57
                           2014 695816500ns'
53F0   Atime               01CFC51864BBECD5 'Sun Aug 31 13:37:57
                           2014 695816500ns'
53F8   Ctime               01CFC518536C84F2 'Sun Aug 31 13:37:28
                           2014 654155400ns'

5400 CENTRAL HEADER #2     02014B50
5404 Created Zip Spec      3F '6.3'
5405 Created OS            00 'MS-DOS'
5406 Extract Zip Spec      14 '2.0'
5407 Extract OS            00 'MS-DOS'
5408 General Purpose Flag  0001
     [Bit  0]              1 'Encryption'
     [Bits 1-2]            0 'Normal Compression'
540A Compression Method    0008 'Deflated'
540C Last Mod Time         451FABEC 'Sun Aug 31 22:31:24 2014'
5410 CRC                   E90636CA
5414 Compressed Length     00005358
5418 Uncompressed Length   00C00036
541C Filename Length       000E
541E Extra Length          0024
5420 Comment Length        0000
5422 Disk Start            0000
5424 Int File Attributes   0000
     [Bit 0]               0 'Binary Data'
5426 Ext File Attributes   00000020
     [Bit 5]               Archive
542A Local Header Offset   00000024
542E Filename              'Taboo/gz1x.bmp'
543C Extra ID #0001        000A 'NTFS FileTimes'
543E   Length              0020
5440   Reserved            00000000
5444   Tag1                0001
5446   Size1               0018
5448   Mtime               01CFC51779A5312D 'Sun Aug 31 13:31:23
                           2014 282257300ns'
5450   Atime               01CFC51838733796 'Sun Aug 31 13:36:43
                           2014 399567000ns'
5458   Ctime               01CFC51838733796 'Sun Aug 31 13:36:43
                           2014 399567000ns'

5460 END CENTRAL HEADER    06054B50
5464 Number of this disk   0000
5466 Central Dir Disk no   0000
5468 Entries in this disk  0002
546A Total Entries         0002
546C Size of Central Dir   000000B8
5470 Offset to Central Dir 000053A8
5474 Comment Length        0000
Done
```